# Thirdy party dependencies in custom class loader(SpringBoot, tomcat).

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, classloader, urlclassloader

I am hosting a SpringBoot1.2.3 app on tomcat, that compiles and run java classes dynamically.

I have a custom class-loader that compiles and load source code at run-time, using Java Compiler Api.

Now I want to allow third party dependencies in compilable code.

I tried using a URLClassLoader to load dependencies from jar files. However, URLClassLoader doesnt work when deployed on tomcat, probably security policy of tomcat is prohibiting this.

I also tried adding dependencies in application itself and sharing it with custom class-loader(which again doesn't work)

e.g. 
If I want to compile and run following code dynamically

```
package a.test;

import a.AClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class ATestClass {
  @Test
  public void testMe() {
    assertThat(1, is(new a.AClass().getOne()));
  }

  @Test
  public void testMeAgain() {
    assertThat(1, is(new AClass().getTwo()));
  }
}
```

Now, how can I provide JUnit dependencies for compilation ?

Comment: have you tried to add it to the classpath of the compiler? I have some experience with this, see my code https://github.com/zhong-j-yu/bayou/blob/0.9/src/bayou/reload/JavacCompiler.java#L256

Comment: Yes, tried that too, but the classes loaded with custom class-loader, cannot see other classes loaded by Tomcat's web app  class-loader....Wondering if I need to create a security manager !!!